# Set up the Firebase reCAPTCHA verifier in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on Firebase Authentication using Phone Number in android. I want to use **reCAPTCHA** in Android app. How can i add this **reCAPTCHA** feature.

Firebase official has a [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) on **reCAPTCHA** implementation. I think it's for web.

Any kind of suggestion or help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Android official

> The SafetyNet service includes a reCAPTCHA API that you can use to
> protect your app from malicious traffic

Here is [SafetyNet reCAPTCHA API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha) official documentation. You can use it in Android Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [official android documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification).

- First, firebase will try to verify your device using SafetyNet

> SafetyNet: If a user has a device with Google Play Services installed, and Firebase Authentication can verify the device as legitimate with Android SafetyNet, phone number sign-in can proceed.

in order to use SafetyNet you **must enable Device Check API** on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com).

- In case of safetyNet can't be used, you have to complete the verification using captcha

> reCAPTCHA verification: In the event that SafetyNet cannot be used, such as when the user does not have Google Play Services support, or when testing your app on an emulator, Firebase Authentication uses a reCAPTCHA verification to complete the phone sign-in flow.